# jquery how to interrupt a looping function when a certain thing == true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've googled this question but can't really find what I'm looking for.

I want to have it so that my function only loops while the page is active and then stops, to prevent unnecessary burden on the browser (not sure if this is even relevant?), but I'm unsure of how to go about this. Here's my looping function:

```
glowy();
function glowy() {
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':1},2000);
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':.2},2000, glowy);
}
```

But I need it so that when

```
if (currentImage !== 1)
```

the function no longer is called, where currentImage is a variable I set a while back to determine what page is active.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks! :-)

Comment: What do you mean when the page is active? When the tab is selected? Or if a certain element is present on the page?

Comment: sorry, by "page is active" i meant when my variable (currentImage) in my code is == 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply interrupt the function by calling `return;` and the remaining code will not execute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Example:_Interrupt_a_function

```
glowy();
function glowy() {
    if (currentImage != 1) {
        return;
    }
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':1},2000);
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':.2},2000, glowy);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I forgot to think about when I go back to when currentImage == 1 to restart the loop. Is this possible?

Comment: When you set `currentImage=1` again, just call `glowy()` immediately afterward again

Comment: Hey thank you! This is a very elegant solution :-) Works perfectly now!

Answer (score 2):

You mean the animation loop? Try this:

```
glowy();
function glowy() {
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':1},2000);
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':.2},2000, currentImage === 1 ? glowy : null);
}
```

To reset the opacity back to 1 while stopping:

```
glowy();
function glowy() {
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':1},2000);
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':.2},2000, function() {
        if(currentImage !== 1) {
            $(this).css('opacity', 1);
        } else {
            glowy();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This does indeed stop the loop when I leave the currentImage == 1, but I forgot to account for going back to currentImage == 1. Is there any way to restart the loop when currentImage == 1 again?

Comment: Also do you think you could explain what occurred in the code? I'm a little confused looking at it. I thought there would have to be a !== in there somewhere.

Comment: I just inverted your condition (keep running if the value is `1`. I'll add a fix for the opacity reset.

Comment: This seems like it should work but the loop isn't restarting when currentImage == 1. It might be a bug with my currentImage variable..

Comment: The loop stopped, it can't know if you changed it back to 1. When you do so, you have to call glowy again.

Answer (score 1):

```
var noglow = false;
glowy();
function glowy() {
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':1},2000);
    if (!noglow) { 
        $('#glow').animate({'opacity':.2},2000, glowy);
    }
}

if (currentImage !== 1) {
    noglow = true;
}
```

OR

```
glowy();
function glowy() {
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':1},2000);
    $('#glow').animate({'opacity':.2},2000, function () {
            if (currentImage === 1) {
                return(glowy);
            }
        return(null);
    });
}
```